# Не отображается, кто преобразовал сообщение в комментарий

Tags: дефект, поддержка, статус-так-задумано, локализация

Точно помню, что раньше в тексте было написано, кто преобразовал сообщение в комментарий. А [тут](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/563355/178988) почему-то не отображается:

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 1):

Странно, но вот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но у меня не так))

Comment: @Qwertiy, это потому что ты автор ответа и тебе показывается другая строка из локализации

Comment: Ну значит надо и в неё добавить?

Answer (score 0):

[Существует множество различных строк](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/79591991?qt=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE), в зависимости от условий совершения действий.

Comment: Меня нет в transifex, так что я этот ответ не понял...

Comment: @Qwertiy суть в том, что движок использует разные строки. Для автора ответа он показывает строку, в которой *нет* информации об авторе изменений. А для всех остальных показывает строку, в которой такая информация *есть*. Не вполне ясно, зачем это было сделано. Вопрос, видимо, к Николаю, а дальше к разработчикам SO.

Comment: @andreycha, но ведь, наверное, можно это информацию добавить.

Comment: @Qwertiy наверное. Это вопрос к разработчикам.

Comment: @Qwertiy С этим могут не согласиться все оставшиеся сообщества сети Stack Exchange. Строки одинаковые везде. На следующей планерке я постараюсь поднять вопрос о причине использования различных строк.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, какая связь со всеми сайтами? Это же локализация? И, если не поставить в строку переменную, то то отображаться будет без пользователя?

Comment: @Qwertiy Строка попадает на Transifex в определенном формате, то есть в ней либо есть переменная для имени пользователя, либо её нет нет. Логика меняется в коде, в случае изменения которого, изменения коснутся всех сайтов сети.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, т. е. текущая версия кода не позволяет отобразить значение переменной? Даже если так, то ведь после добавления такой возможности, переменная сама в локализационных строках не появится, следовательно, визуально не будет изменений для других сайтов. Или нет?